# If statement stopping a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I'm making a table that calls the following method when the value is changed, but the update method dies part through if the variable stuntSet is set to "all"

When I call updateStunts, if stuntSet is set to "all" it never gets out of the for loop. When it's set to anything else it seems to work fine and moves on to call countStuntRefresh(). The strange part is that it completes all the code inside the if statement that checks if stuntSet ==="all" but it never reaches the call for countStuntRefresh();

I've been going through this for an hour and I can't find my mistake. I apologize if it's a simple mistake and I appreciate whatever help you can give.

http://jsbin.com/nicoruvamula/1/
is the link to the full code

```
var selected = false;
var updateStunts = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < character.stunts.length; i++) {
        if (stuntSet === "all") {
            selected = document.getElementById("select" + character.stunts[i].name).checked;
            character.stunts[i].chosen = selected;
        } else if( stuntSet === character.stunts[i].category) {
            selected = document.getElementById("select" + character.stunts[i].name).checked;
            character.stunts[i].chosen = selected;
        }
    }
    countStuntRefresh();
};

var countStuntRefresh = function() {

    character.spentRefresh = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i <character.stunts.length; i++){
        if (character.stunts[i].chosen) {
            character.spentRefresh += character.stunts[i].cost;
        }
        document.getElementById("stunttest").innerHTML = "Spent Refresh:" + character.spentRefresh;
    }
};
```

Comment: What's the point of the if statement if they both do the same thing?

Comment: ^ More correctly, this is equivalent: `if (stuntSet === "all" || stuntSet === character.stunts[i].category)`.

Comment: I probably should have used || between the two. There are many different categories and it was to limit which character.stunts chosen properties were affected.

Comment: Also, see my comment on Tim's answer. You should add an additional var to your Stunt object like `this.safeid = name.replace(/ /g,'-');` and use the safeid for, well, the ids of the various selects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run the jsbin code, there are several exceptions because `document.getElementById("select" + character.stunts[i].name)` returns null.

Looking through the code, I noticed that you don't wait for the DOM-ready event. As you already including jQuery, have you tried wrapping your code in a

```
$(function() { /* your code*/ });
```

(or will jsbin automagically call your code in onload or DOMReady? not familiar with jsbin...)

Comment: The reason for returning null (or rather undefined) lies in the ids: `<input type="checkbox" onchange="updateStunts()" id="selectCorner of My Eye">`. The ID is probably supposed to be one "word" like `selectCorner-of-My-Eye`.

Comment: I'll try the IDs. What I don't understand is when I place stuntSet to Alertness, the "Corner of My Eye" works perfectly. It stops working when stuntSet is set to All. I don't understand why one would work and the other would not.

Comment: Paul it worked! It wasn't the spaces causing the problem, but some of the id's had an apostrophe, and that shut them down. That's why it worked on the groups with spaces, but couldn't go through the whole list. I used the replace line to remove the apostrophe's and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I wished there was a checkmark I could put next to your comment. Thanks everyone.